# How to add custom class in Magento 2 Category page?

Tags: magento2, category, class

I want to add custom class in Magento 2 category page like in

column main and sidebar sidebar-main

How to add custom class with these class ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where you want to use this ?

Comment: on category page i just want to show sidebar after menu then my all products @AmitBera

Answer (score 2):

Check the relevant page layout, for example:

```
/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/page_layout/2columns-left.xml
```

This contains the column containers like:

```
<referenceContainer name="columns">
    <container name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main" after="main">
        <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main"/>
    </container>
    <container name="div.sidebar.additional" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-additional" after="div.sidebar.main">
        <container name="sidebar.additional" as="sidebar_additional" label="Sidebar Additional"/>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Replicate layout file in your own theme, like:

```
/app/design/frontend/<Vendor_Name>/<Theme>/Magento_Theme/page_layout/2columns-left.xml
```

Add classes in `htmlClass` accordingly like 'test123' below:

```
<referenceContainer name="columns">
    <container name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main" after="main">
        <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main"/>
    </container>
    <container name="div.sidebar.additional" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-additional test123" after="div.sidebar.main">
        <container name="sidebar.additional" as="sidebar_additional" label="Sidebar Additional"/>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Run commands to compile etc and refresh frontend to check if you see new class.

This is tested and works in v2.3.x.

Answer (score 0):

I have same requirement for add class on category content, i used **htmlClass** on content area as below **newarrival_custom_category**, it works.

For add class on body tag, Use class name attribute after body, the class will be added on body tag of category page.

Ex.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>     
        <attribute name="class" value="newarrival_category"/>
        <referenceContainer name="content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="newarrival_custom_category">
        ...
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
    </page>
```

**newarrival_category** will be added on category body tag and

**newarrival_custom_category** will be added on content area.

Answer (score -1):

already custom class add in body tag, you can use that class

https://drops.meetanshi.com/H0s5yj

Comment: Thanks for your response Which class will you please tell me @Jiga

Comment: for every category page its catalog-category-view and for particular category its using class

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

In your layout or template file, you need to add an attribute to the body tag, like this:

```
<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="my-css-class"/>
    ...
```

Hope that Helps

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @zigojacko please add right ans.

Comment: Answer added @Jigar Patel.

Comment: Thanks @zigojacko